# A problem in ANOVA, I think the result will be useful but I do not know how to prove it.

Tags: statistics, least-squares, data-analysis, anova

Consider an ANOVA model:
$$y_{ijl}=\mu+\alpha_{i}+\beta_{j}+\epsilon_{ijl}$$
where $i=1,2\dots I, j=1,2\dots J, l=1,2\dots n_{ij}, \epsilon_{ijl}\sim N(0,\sigma^2) 
$i.i.d, we also have the constrains to ensure identifiability:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{I}\alpha_i=0, \sum_{j=1}^J\beta_j=0$$
Show that the estimations for $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$, which are denoted by $\hat{\alpha}_i, \hat{\beta}_j$, are uncorrelated if and only if the following holds:
$$n_{ij}=\frac{n_{i.}n_{.j}}{n_{..}}$$
where:
$$n_{i.}=\sum_{j=1}^Jn_{ij}, n_{.j}=\sum_{i=1}^In_{ij}, n_{..}=\sum_{i,j}n_{ij}$$
(I think the result is consice and beautiful, but I cannot figure it out. I guess there must be some tricks, but I don't know where they are!)